# 27512 pinout and PCB layout

Tags: pcb-design, layout, eeprom, pinout

I'm trying to design PCB traces for a 27512 EPROM chip. But its pinout for the higher half of the address bus seems completely illogical to me and I cannot imagine how should I lay out my traces for it. Here's how the pinout looks like:

[image]

Other components have the data and address bus pins in order, so I need (and I would prefer) to keep it that way.

27512 has it in order, too, but only for the lower half of the address bus (A0..A7) and data bus (D0..D7); although the data bus goes around the bottom of the chip and around the ground pin (so I would need to trace it in some other direction or use a jumper wire to jump over my data bus).

But the upper half of the address bus jumps all around the chip and doesn't seem to follow any particular order: first it goes down (A8,A9), then it goes up starting from a completely different pin (A10,A11), and then jumps to the other side of the chip, then it jumps back to move up again, and then jumps to the other corner :-/

This is really weird to me, and I don't know how to make it in order again (especially to keep up with the order of the lower half of the address bus).

*So my question is:*

**Is there any clever logic behind all this jumping around?** I cannot imagine that the designers of the chip just put the pinout randomly (especially when they kept the order of two other buses well enough). I'm more likely to believe that *they had some particular sophisticated PCB layout in mind when designing it*. But I also cannot see the logic behind it.

I also took a look at other EPROM and SRAM chips and they all seem to have this very same pinout design, so I guess there *was* some rationale to keep it that way. But the PCB layout for this particular layout isn't very obvious to me. **Is there any standard way to lay out the traces for these memory chips I should know of?** Because without it, I would have to make a lot of jumpers on my PCB (one-sided) to restore the correct ordering of the bus lines.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the pinout of smaller chips yet? You may find a clue there.

Comment: Well, if you mean the chips of smaller memory capacity & smaller number of pins, then yes. I looked at them (as I already wrote). What I guess is that they started with the smaller ones (e.g.2716), turning the data bus around the top of the chip (from A7 to A8,A9) in order. Then jumping over Vpp and /OE to A10 (still in order). But when extending the chips to higher capacities, they also needed to extend the top of the chip and add the address pins there, keepin the backward compatibility with previous chips. But they don't keep it backward-compatible for /CE and Vpp pins: they change place.

Comment: Also, this doesn't solve my problem of how should I lay out the traces now :/

Comment: Also remember that multiplexed buses used to be all the rage (and can still be found these days), so having A0-7 and D0-7 lined up was important, and the rest could be woven around as required.

Comment: Anyways, split the high address bits out the right side instead of trying to squeeze them out the left.

Comment: Hmm good idea, worth trying. I could trace the A12 between pins 25 and 26, so I would have A12..A15 right. Now I need to figure out how to make the other four in order...

Comment: Another option would be to solve it "in software". That would mean you have to figure out what the address space would look like if you swap two or more pins. Poor choice when it comes to software maintainability though.

Comment: Also, don't be afraid to reorder address lines; your upload files would have to be reordered, but routing would be simplified.

Comment: You can route the traces however you like (or use an autorouter if it's not terribly important), but one thing I've learned is that you should try to keep digital and analog traces separated. That also means splitting the ground plane so that digital signals are routed under the digital ground plane, and similarly for analog signals. The two should be tied at one point. See this link: http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5450

Comment: @Ignacio: Sure, I could just renumber the pins to have them in order on my board: the data in EEPROM will just interlace in some other addressing scheme, but the addresses would remain consistent throughout the operation. At least as long as I won't use any programmer which uses the official ordering from the datasheet :P Which is very likely, so it would be better to keep up with the standard numbering.

Comment: @HariGanti: They're all digital. "A" stands for "address" and "D" for "data".

Comment: Wow, I completely managed to miss that. My bad, though the article does still provide some good routing advice.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the answer is simply historical carry over maintaining pin compatability (originally going back to the '08' chip - 1K ROM).

Compare the pinout with is its much older cousin the 2716 (EPROM) - a 24 pin chip. In the 'good old days' this was the basis for developing a lot of the earlier microcomputers.

[image]

When more address lines were needed (A11 - A15) they fitted them into the extra pins. Pin 28 was designated for power so the original pin 24 (now = pin 26) was available to connect an extra address line (A13) leaving A8 and A9  and A10 in their original positions. Vpp (programming voltage on old pin 21 was not required) so this became A11 (new pin 23). This left new pins 1,2 and 27 to assign to A15, A12 and A14.

This effectively allowed older 24 ROMS and EPROMS (and RAM chips such as the 6116) to be plugged into the later (28 pin) designs.

[image]

As regards PCB traces (I'm assuming your using at least double sided) there is no problem with the order. You are simply connecting pin 1 to pin 1, pin 2 to pin 2 etc. by taking the (horizontal) trace between pins, remembering you have both sides of the board to play with. If you require the address bus in a particular 'order' bring out the horizontal traces from the memory block and use vias and perpendicular traces to re-order them.

Comment: It may be worth noting that things like VPP got bounced around because of a desire to avoid pushing to the next package size.  When there are enough pins available to have VPP as a separate signal, it often is, but when the package fills up, it gets combined with something else.  BTW, one thing I find slightly curious is that while many circuits needed an active high chip enable, mask-ROM chips had that as a standard option, and many standard EPROM/OTPROMs required VPP to be high, none of the EPROM/OTPROMs documented it as being usable as an active-high chip enable.

Comment: @supercat some very good points well made (+1 from me)